# How does Xcode determine which build config to use with custom build configs and multiple projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've added a Distribution build configuration (dupe of Release) to my main project, and other projects in the workspace that the main project depends on (frameworks & static libraries) only have the standard Debug & Release configurations.

When building with this new configuration, the build log says that the other frameworks & static libraries are being built with the Distribution configuration — but those projects don't have a Distribution configuration.

What's going on here? How is Xcode determining what config to use for these other projects in the workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has come from the [same question on the dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/969003).

> 'Distribution', vs. 'Debug' & 'Release' is no longer used. Now it's
>   just the two.

So it seems that you should really only use the two default build configurations, at least if you're dealing with workspaces and dependant projects.

I was following instructions for setting up beta versions of apps from the [Building, Archiving, and Submitting Your App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#414) WWDC Talk in 2012. They mentioned adding a new build config called "Distribution", however it seems that information is now out of date, and Xcode has moved on!